# Checking if a remote iDRAC is running iDRAC 6 or 7 via RACADM

Tags: dell, drac

I have about 50 remote remote servers with iDRACs that I need to inventory. I'm able to pull most of the information I need using RACADM, but one thing I'm unable to figure out how to access is whether the target is running iDRAC 6 or 7. I could obviously just go to the web interface, look, and write it down, but I want to do it in a way that's scriptable. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a year later, I've figured out a method to do it. It's not through RACADM, but it's not terribly complicated to script either. Making a request to `https://dracaddress/cgi-bin/discover` will return XML with this format:

```
<DISCOVER>
    <RESP>
        <RC>0x0</RC>
        <ENDPOINTTYPE>iDRAC7</ENDPOINTTYPE>
        <ENDPOINTVER>1.00</ENDPOINTVER>
        <PROTOCOLTYPE>HTTPS</PROTOCOLTYPE>
        <PROTOCOLVER>2.0</PROTOCOLVER>
    </RESP>
</DISCOVER>
```

Parsing that and getting the value for `ENDPOINTTYPE` will tell you what model device you're connecting to.